# Undefined index: HOOK_EGR_FBLOGIN in Prestashop 1.5.6

Tags: prestashop

After moving Prestashop 1.5.6 from one hosting account to another, I'm getting this error

```
[PHP Notice #8] Undefined index: HOOK_EGR_FBLOGIN (../cache/smarty/compile/fd/38/70/fd387050447e4a11ece14a89564334593361be9e.file.header.tpl.php, line 176)
```

This is an error related to a facebook login module. Anyone knows where and how this index the error talks about should be defined?

Answer (score 1):

There is an undefined variable in your header.tpl file in your Facebook module. Open the file, look somewhere around line 176 and enclose the code in

```
{if isset($HOOK_EGR_FBLOGIN)}
.
.
.
{/if}
```

Then clean your cache.